# What is the best open-source java charting library? (other than jfreechart)

Tags: java, charts, plot

Why are there not more opensource easy to use charting libraries for Java?. The only successful opensource project in this area seems to be jfreechart, and it doesn't even have any documentation or examples available.

Comment: Free java charting framework for Java Swing : http://frontangle.com/#/icharts/ . You can do most types of charts in this

Comment: first off, I believe, no good comes out of closing questions. period.
for who ever end up in this page looking for an alternative, try [`XChart`](https://github.com/knowm/XChart) (also mentioned below by @herrtim). looks promising.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

There is [charts4j](https://github.com/julienchastang/charts4j) which is a charts and graphs API. It enables developers to programmatically create the charts available in the [Google Chart API](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/) through a straightforward and intuitive Java API.

Disclaimer: I wrote [charts4j](https://github.com/julienchastang/charts4j). We will be doing another major release in the next few weeks.

Comment: Good job! The only downside is the need for an internet conection, though I cant remenber when was the last time I was disconnected.
;-)

Comment: @pyinsci: some shops prevent servers from connecting to external internet servers (even if the servers are reachable from the internet) for security reasons.

Comment: Notice that the Google static charts API has been deprecated since April 20, 2012

Comment: An alternative API that doesn't need to connect to external Internet servers is [XChart](https://github.com/timmolter/XChart).

Comment: If you're targeting Web browser, you can take a look at [ZK Charts](http://www.zkoss.org/zkchartsdemo/line_basic).

Comment: Iceberg Charts : https://github.com/oliverwatkins/Iceberg-Charts/wiki is quick and easy to get started

Comment: Is it still working in 2016? :D Any other libraries that uses Google Charts?

Comment: Does it generate SVG?

Answer (score 59):

There aren't a lot of them because they would be in competition with [JFreeChart](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/), and it's awesome.  You can get documentation and examples by downloading the [developer's guide](http://www.object-refinery.com/jfreechart/guide.html).  There are also tons of free online tutorials if you search for them.

- [JFreeChart - Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JFreeChart/article.html)
- [Introduction to JFreeChart](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/650480/Introduction-to-JFreeChart)

Comment: One very useful contribution to jfreechart was a simple API That would allow you the generate a plot with a simple function call like so: plot(array) and get a chart object in return which you could futher customize, i.e. add a title, gridlines, etc...

Comment: for some things (high-speed mathematical plotting) jfreechart is mediocre, not awesome.

Comment: @JasonS What do you use for that?

Comment: I don't, not in Java. I found JChart2D better than JFreeChart, but it had its limitations as well; for one project I ended up making my own graphing library, a painful experience but it did what I needed. I wish that a port of Python's matplotlib were available in Java.

Comment: yes downloading the developer's guide for $65.00....

Comment: Calling JFreeChart "awesome" is overstating it. "Awesome for simple stuff" might be more accurate. +1 for a matplotlib clone for Java

Comment: Tutorial link is dead.

Comment: @JasonS, I'm not sure how "high-speed" you're talking about. I have integrated JFreeChart into our application doing mathematical simulates. The simulation engine is really fast and we plot the plots in real time and are able to update dozens of graphs (each with 2-6 line plots) as the user adjusts parameters by dragging their fingers across the trackpad over the parameter to change the value in real time. There is zero lag and a high enough frame rate that it's smooth as butter. Is that high-speed mathematical plotting? Of course it's now 2021, but we've been doing this since 2010.

Comment: My complaint about JFreeChart is that the charts are ugly. This is of course an opinion. The font's are pixelated or blurry (antialiasing is poor) and same with the lines. The library is not taking advantage of the resolution available to it while other parts of Java are and drawing beautiful fonts and lines. The contrast is stark making the JFreeChart graphics look like they're from the 1990's while the rest of the application looks modern.

Comment: Output from things like Google's Chart API are incredibly beautiful compared to JFreeChart, but this is not integrated locally... it would be a remote service.

Comment: Tried to install it, it's completely broken and old

Comment: @Mouvre This question and answer are from 2008.

Comment: I have since updated my JFreeChart library to the latest version, which has support for HiDPI displays. I may have made a few other changes. The pixelation and blurry fonts are now gone and things look much better. I still think Google's charts look better, but the graphs drawn in JFreeChart in my application are no longer ugly in my opinion. So I retract my statement about the charts being ugly.

Answer (score 15):

EasyCharts is commercial so i couldn't use it for my project. I used the GRAL graphing library instead. I found it very easy to customize and it's licensed under LGPL just like JFreeChart, so you can use it for free:

[http://trac.erichseifert.de/gral](http://trac.erichseifert.de/gral/)

Comment: I know it is too late, but I am searching for documentation, not able to find one. Can you please share, if you have anything?

Comment: Check out iceberg charts : http://frontangle.com/icharts/ I created it. I think its up there with JFreechart and all the rest.

Answer (score 14):

Good question, I was just looking for alternatives to JFreeChart myself the other day.  JFreeChart is excellent and very comprehensive, I've used it on several projects.  My recent problem was that it meant adding 1.6mb of libraries to a 50kb applet, so I was looking for something smaller.

The [JFreeChart FAQ](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/faq.html#FAQ13) itself lists alternatives.  Compared to JFreeChart, most of them are pretty basic, and some pretty ugly.  The most promising seem to be the [Java Chart Construction Kit](http://jcckit.sourceforge.net/) and [OpenChart2](http://approximatrix.com/products/openchart2/).

I also found [EasyCharts](http://www.objectplanet.com/easycharts/), which is a commercial product but seemingly free to use in some circumstances.

In the end, I went back to the tried and trusted JFreeChart and used [Proguard](http://proguard.sourceforge.net) to butcher it into a more manageable size.

I suggest that you take another look at JFreeChart.  The user guide is only available to buy, but the [demo](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/samples.html) shows what is possible and it's pretty easy to work out how from the [API documentation](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/index.html).  Basically you start with the [ChartFactory](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/ChartFactory.html) static methods and plug the resultant [JFreeChart](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/JFreeChart.html) object into a [ChartPanel](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/ChartPanel.html) to display it.  If you get stuck, I'm sure you'll get some quick answers to your problems on StackOverflow.

Comment: I created a simple "plot" wrapper around java chart construction kit, which makes it really easy to use for simple plots https://bitbucket.org/hughperkins/easyjcckit

Answer (score 6):

You can try [Jzy3d](http://www.jzy3d.org/). It helps drawing simple 3d charts (surfaces, scatters, bars, etc), and has lot of options for customizing layout of axes, ticks, etc. There are lot of examples and a documentation on the wiki.

It's free and open source.

Cheers,

Martin

Answer (score 5):

For dynamic 2D charts, I have been using [JChart2D](http://jchart2d.sourceforge.net/). It's fast, simple, and being updated regularly. The author has been quick to respond to my one bug report and few feature requests. We, at our company, prefer it over JFreeChart because it was designed for dynamic use, unlike JFreeChart.

Answer (score 4):

There is JChart which is all open source.  I'm not sure exactly what you are graphing and how you are graphing it (servlets, swing, etc) so I would say just look at a couple different ones and see which works for you.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/jchart/

I've also used JGraph but I've only used their commercial version.  They do offer an open source version however:

https://github.com/jgraph/jgraphx

Answer (score 4):

There is a new charting library in town: [JChartlib](http://freshmeat.net/projects/jchartlib) JChartLib http://freshmeat.net/projects/jchartlib

Comment: It looks great!! Lightweight and no dependencies, wow, nice work. I took a look at the the wiki, pretty straightforward. My question: does it allow categories instead of numeric values on the X axis?

Comment: Wow, cool thanks for comment. The number of series are actually not limited in the linecharts. It draws as many charts as you like. I just released a new version that is able to save the chart to a jpg or png file. More chart type like barchart, cakechart, radarchart and so on are in the planning.

Comment: okay, let me try this one before it getting old... :D

Comment: It's GPL.  Please can you make it LGPL?  (Or Apache 2, or MPL)

Comment: The main reason why I would consider using a different charting library other than jfreechart is that it would be nice to have a charting library that is (i) maintained by a community (ii) has decent documentation about how to use it available for free.  Unfortunately jchartlib offers no advantage on either of these points :-(

Answer (score 2):

I found this framework: jensoft sw2d, free for non commercial use (dual licensing)

http://www.jensoft.org

regards.

Comment: This site mentions that sw2d is licensed using the LGPL; isn't that free to use in both open-source and commercial tools?

Answer (score 1):

I've used EasyCharts in the past and it lived up to it's name. It's not as powerful as JFreeChart, but the JAR for EasyCharts is much smaller than for JFreeChart.