# Java vertical bar chart

Tags: dll, charts, java

I need to create vertical bar charts in java, and wasn't able to find libraries for doing this. 
Are there any simple, but still good for handling a lot of data, libraries?
Thanks a lot

Comment: If you want what is "good", you ought to specify what you would consider to be "good", otherwise your question is too subjective.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pie, Bar, Line charts in java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2669502/pie-bar-line-charts-in-java)

Comment: @Raedwald Yes, it is almost a subjective question, since I just wanted to know wich you may like the most

Comment: "wich you may like the most": please read the FAQ. Such questions are inappropriate for this site.

Comment: Ok, I am gonna edit the question, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi there a lots of library's for creating vertival bar charts.

here you have one:
http://www.jpowered.com/java-bean/graph-chart/vertical-bar-graph/

and here a other:

http://www.javatao.com/content/view/13/12/

Comment: I actually like the javatao most, thanks

Comment: ^^ same here, your welcome.

Answer (score 1):

JFreeChart is your friend. It has many others including what you need. Details can be found at following link
http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/

Following site has an example for vertical bar chart.
http://www.roseindia.net/chartgraphs/bar-chart-JFree.shtml

Comment: Thanks, the jree is actually really interesting, but i like javatao more fro vertical bars
Thanks anyway