# Java Visualisation / Charting library like Google Charts / Visualisation

Tags: java, charts

Unfortunately Google Charts / Visualisations is not available for download in any form. I require a standalone library for numerous reasons and using the services offered by Google is not a satisfactory option.

Id like more options than

- JFreeChart

Comment: Are you looking for something interactive (web) charting or static charting as JFreeChart (which can produce some nice charts)

Comment: Should it be open/free?

Answer (score 1):

[Prefuse](http://prefuse.org/) is the winner. [You can find more here](http://abeautifulwww.com/2008/09/08/20-useful-visualization-libraries/) with few sample visualizations for each library.

The [JFreeChart](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/faq.html#FAQ13) lists some opensource alternatives and I've also found a similar question in SO here: [What is the best open-source java charting library? (other than jfreechart)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/265777/what-is-the-best-open-source-java-charting-library-other-than-jfreechart)
 and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/527640/java-graph-or-chart-library)

Comment: Notes for others prefuse has not been updated in over 3 years. The link however is interesting and worth a look.

Answer (score 1):

I just used [GRAL](http://trac.erichseifert.de/gral) (GRAphing Library), and it's great. very simple, lightweight (unlike JFreChart). You can see examples of the resulting plots [there](http://trac.erichseifert.de/gral/wiki/Gallery).

Answer (score 0):

[This page lists](http://java-source.net/open-source/charting-and-reporting) some other charting software for Java. Maybe one of them would suit your needs.

Comment: i find those sort of lists on java.net often incomplete/of date. Its better to get real opinions from real developers like you :)