# Simple Java library for graphing mathematical functions/equations

Tags: java, math, graph

I'm looking (have looked on Google, no luck) for a Java library that can produce graphs of *mathematical functions and equations*. It would be great if I could us it as a JComponent for adding to frames, but I can do without. If there aren't any good ones I'll probably make one anyway.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your question is off topic. Please read the Help Center.

Comment: I did read the help center, how is it off topic?

Comment: Library recommendation, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: How would you recommend I ask the question?

Comment: I wouldn't. Asking for software recommendations is off-topic.

Comment: How would you recommend I ask a directly answerable, non-opinionated question on how to draw a graph?

Comment: That depends on the problem. [Here's a good article describing how to ask a good question.](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4529055/java-visualisation-charting-library-like-google-charts-visualisation/14067290#14067290

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you check jfreechart?

http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/samples.html

As jfreechart uses data series you will have to sample your matchematical functions.

Comment: Thanks, I did come across it, i didn't realise it had a data series mode. That'll greatly reduce the code i have to write.