# What is a simple way to generate a line chart in Java?

Tags: java, graph, charts, line, axis

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the best open-source java charting library? (other than jfreechart)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/265777/what-is-the-best-open-source-java-charting-library-other-than-jfreechart)

I am writing a Java application which requires me to generate line charts (basically an XY graph where x-axis is a date and the y-axis is a currency exchange rate, i.e., a float). I was wondering what could be the easiest way to do this. I was thinking an easy way would be to find a good library but I could not do so.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try JFreechart http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/samples.html

Answer (score 1):

You could not ? Are you joking?
http://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=java+chart+library

Second link is  [What is the best open-source java charting library? (other than jfreechart)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/265777/what-is-the-best-open-source-java-charting-library-other-than-jfreechart)
and three others are FOSS Java libraries...

Comment: obviously i found out about jfreechart, but that library is much comprehensive, i need something easy to adapt

Comment: This is exactly the question asked by @fccoelho in his aforequoted question.

Comment: @temelm: from a technical perspective it is a complex task...