# Charts in web application Java

Tags: charts, web

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the best open-source java charting library? (other than jfreechart)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/265777/what-is-the-best-open-source-java-charting-library-other-than-jfreechart)

In my web application I need to present some charts. I create class where I used JFreeChart library, but this library is desktop library. I need some free web library. Can you help me?

Comment: There is already a discussion for this
[What is the best open-source java charting library?][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/265777/what-is-the-best-open-source-java-charting-library-other-than-jfreechart

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the [Google Chart Tools](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/); the simple web service interface is easily usable via JavaScript for live graphics and the [Google Chart API](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/image/) is great for Java (and other languages) for [static images](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/image/docs/making_charts.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can create chart for your web application by using JFreeChart as well. For more details go to following link:
http://himtech-spring.blogspot.com/2012/07/spring-mvc-with-jfreechart.html

You can also create chart for web application using Google chart API. For this you need to construct an URL and send it to Google chart server for generating chart.
[Click here for Google chart integration with SpringMVC implementation](http://himtech-spring.blogspot.com/2012/07/spring-mvc-with-google-chart.html)

Answer (score 0):

[gRaphäel](http://g.raphaeljs.com/) provides charts with a JavaScript API.

Answer (score 0):

You can use kava charts in java.  You can refer this link: http://www.kavachart.com/documentation/index.html

Answer (score 0):

## Server side

- [JFreeChart](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/) can be used in web applications as well. Simply create a servlet that returns a chart [rendered as PNG](http://javabeanz.wordpress.com/2007/07/10/displaying-dynamic-charts-in-a-jsp-page-jfreechart/)

## Client side

- [Google Chart Tools](http://code.google.com/apis/chart) - easy way to generate charts by crafting URLs
- [Various JavaScript charting libraries](http://www.splashnology.com/article/15-awesome-free-javascript-charts/325/), with [jqPlot](http://www.jqplot.com/) and [HighCharts](http://www.highcharts.com/) being my favourite