# Organizational chart/tree in Java

Tags: java, charts, tree

I am trying to make an organizational chart/tree in Java.  I tried using Prefuse, but its library was very buggy and I am a bit of a beginner with programming.  I also looked into using google's chart tools, but it is JavaScript based.  I need to use Java and not JavaScript because I need access to local files.  How should I go about doing this?

Comment: What problems did you experience with [Prefuse](http://prefuse.org/)? Being a beginner, you are likely to experience issues regardless of what library(s) you are using.

Comment: Have you looked at this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/265777/what-is-the-best-open-source-java-charting-library-other-than-jfreechart

Comment: Almost every java file in the library had errors, and most of those I couldn't fix.  Could that have something to do with the IDE I'm using?

Comment: In what way did every java file in the library have errors? Perhaps you may want to ask questions about those.

Answer (score 1):

There is organisation chart component already implemented in Vaadin you can find and download it [here](http://www.lexaden.com/main/entry/lexaden_organisation_chart)

Comment: Link is gone...!

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used Prefuse before but perhaps [JGraphT](http://jgrapht.org/) may work for you, assuming your organizational chart can be modeled as a graph.

Comment: Thank you.  I am currently looking into it.