# RESTful graphing application or web service

Tags: graph, diagnostics

#### Problem

Have a server-side application that generates a large amount of logging and statistical data that needs to be analyzed for the purposes of monitoring and diagnostics.

Currently, we use a Javascript graphing library to request the information from the server and graph it  in a web browser. However, this requires a lot of developer hours in designing the UX and implementing the graphing functionality.

#### Question

Is there a better way to do this? Perhaps a web service or desktop application that can request the information from our servers and display it in the way that we need to see it?

**Example of what we have now:**

[image]

Comment: Are some of the things you're trying to graph something that [javamelody](http://code.google.com/p/javamelody/) could manage for you?  Are you looking for a package to consume raw generic data and perform statistic analysis on it?

Comment: We need something that will help us visualize data. We do not need analysis.

Comment: I would suggest checking out [this question (older)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/265777/what-is-the-best-open-source-java-charting-library-other-than-jfreechart) or typing "jfreechart vs" into google and checking out some of it's auto-complete suggestions to see some other libraries.  And of course, there's [jfreechart](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

you want a dashboard as a service.

http://www.clicdata.com/

https://www.geckoboard.com/

https://plot.ly/