# Java Swing bars floating instead of starting from the same baseline

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jpanel, flowlayout

I'm very new to Java Swing and I'm currently trying to make a simple bar chart that visualises bubble sort algorithm. I developed the code to scale the bars depending on user inputted values, but I'm facing a problem where the bars are floating and they seem to be centered in the middle(?) like the image below
[Floating bars error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m3mS6.png)

My code is as follows:

```
    JPanel barPanel = new JPanel();
    barPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    // Default bars
    int[] values = {29, 14, 90, 22, 41, 11, 3};
    int maxBarHeight = 200;  // Maximum height for the bars

    for (int value : values) {
        int barHeight = (int) ((double) value / Arrays.stream(values).max().getAsInt() * maxBarHeight);
        JLabel bar = new JLabel(" ");
        bar.setBackground(Color.ORANGE);
        bar.setOpaque(true);
        bar.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(30, barHeight));
        barPanel.add(bar);
    }

    menuPanel.add(visualizerPanel);
    menuPanel.add(barPanel);
```

Thank you for your help!

This is what I wish to achieve:
[Simple bar chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xpDBY.png)

I have tried using BorderLayout and BoxLayout. The former resulted in only one long skinny bar being displayed. The latter didn't work quite as well too as only one bar is displayed.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/265777/what-is-the-best-open-source-java-charting-library-other-than-jfreechart

Comment: I highly recommend not re-inventing the wheel here. But if you are dead set on doing it, you might want to look the `Area` classes in this package here: https://sourceforge.net/p/tus/code/HEAD/tree/tjacobs/ui/shape/ this is a package for treating `Shape`s like full-fledged Components.

Comment: If you are going to have to create your own Swing bar chart displaying program, don't make the bars JLabels or any other component type of object. Instead, create a single JPanel to draw the chart, and display the bars as drawn rectangles within that drawing JPanel.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64196256/131872 for an example of animating a BubbleSort.

Comment: [JFreeChart](https://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/)

Comment: So much for taking the time to explain "why" your current code has a problem. Since you are new to Swing,  I thought that might be beneficial the next time you create a layout where you actually need to use real components and not do custom painting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is likely caused by the FlowLayout you are using.

It is much easier to subclass JPanel, then override the paintComponent(Graphics) method to perform custom painting.
Advantage: If the area you need is too big for the screen, you can resize the window and easily stuff your custom component into a JScrollPane.

There are lots of examples available, and a fine tutorial as well:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html

So highlevel your code could look like this:

- Define data array to be sorted
- Have the paintComponent method render this data to your taste
- Have a method that performs one sort iteration
- Use a Swing Timer to periodically call your sort iteration method and then call repaint()

Main method:

- Initialize to be sorted data
- Create the Window hosting your component
- Start the timer

Answer (score 0):

> but I'm facing a problem where the bars are floating and they seem to be centered in the middle(?)

All Swing components have an `alignmentX/Y` property which a layout manager can use (or ignore) when doing the layout.

A FlowLayout ignores this property and vertically centers all the components.

> I have tried using BoxLayout.

Yes a `BoxLayout` will respect the alignment property. You will need to set this property on all the components.

However, the `BoxLayout` also respects the "maximum size" so you will also need to set the maximum size equal to the preferred size.

You will need changes like:

```
//barPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
barPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(barPanel, BoxLayout.X_Axis));

...

bar.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(30, barHeight));
bar.setMaximumSize(bar.getPreferredSize() );
```

However, as mentioned in comments from above, the preferred approach is to do custom painting. It will definitely make animation the bar chart easier.

I included the above information to better help you understand layout managers and how to use them effectively.